# I can't find init script for ldap on version 2.4.45

Tags: openldap

slapd executable file is not present in /etc/rc.d/init.d and also slapd.d directory is not present.
Please suggest me how to create it.

PS: I am able to start ldap with file "/usr/local/libexec/slapd"

Comment: Then you didn't look in the right place. What the right place is depends on your operating system. Off topic.

Comment: I am using RHEL7